# Unable to runserver Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, server, django-views

I am unable to runserver in a Django-Python code.

I read that it could be related to the models.py file.

Here is the file:

```
from django.db import models


class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about"""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __Str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model"""
        return self.text



class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about the topic."""
    topic = models.ForeignKey('Topic',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model"""
        return self.text[:50] + "..."
```

Comment: What is your problem, please give more detail.

Comment: @Lucas Batista, is there any error? Please share

Comment: @Lucas Batista please show us the error when you run `python manage.py runserver`. All letters in your special method __str__ must be lowercase, maybe the error come from here

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, tell us what type of error you are getting then only we can help you better.

Secondly, lower that capital 'S' which you defined after topic class it should be like,

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.text
```